# create table DDL export excluding primary key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

trying to export the table creation DDL script using `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMP')`.
RESULT:

```
CREATE TABLE "ALEX"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO", "ENAME") ENABLE
    );
```

here  i need to exclude the primary key creation step  ,PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO", "ENAME") ENABLE

i could use  the following , but with this other constraints are being filtered

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS',false );
```

expected :

```
 CREATE TABLE "ALEX"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
    );
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract only specific constraints?
Oracle allows either taking full table definition (with constraints) or partial (only the table def, no constraints at all - and if you need the constraints you'll have to extract them one by one manually) as far as I know, so I do not think you can grab the table definition without the PK but with FK's.. I think you'll have to edit it by hand...

Comment: `CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER` might make it easier to edit out a specific constraint, but I don't think there's any way to do it automatically. Kind of curious why you'd want to exclude the PK though.